# How to Write SQL data to Excel File

Tags: sql, vb.net, export-to-excel

I have a Basic VB.net Program that runs a query and reports the results to a message box.  What i'd like to do is report the results to an excel spreasheet that exists on my computer (C:\Test.xls).  I want to use `A1 (Item 0), A2 (Item1), and A3 (Item2)` (cells) to report the 3 items I am selecting from the SQL command.  How can I do this?  Below is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connectionString As String
        Dim sqlCnn As SqlConnection
        Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
        Dim sql As String


        connectionString = "Data Source=10.0.1.1;Initial Catalog=Database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login;Password=password"
        sql = "select * from tickets where sticket_number = 'W408259'"

        sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Try
            sqlCnn.Open()
            sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn)
            Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
            While sqlReader.Read()
                MsgBox(sqlReader.Item(0) & "  -  " & sqlReader.Item(1) & "  -  " & sqlReader.Item(2))
            End While
            sqlReader.Close()
            sqlCmd.Dispose()
            sqlCnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You'll need to add a reference to Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library. After that you can use Excel functions :)

Comment: Have you tried any excel functions already? Try something, I'll help you finish this. I know exactly what you want but you'll have to show me something where I can tap in :)

Comment: Do I need to use the Excel Object Library?  The idea is to automate this... and the server I'm running it on probably won't have Microsoft Excel.  Do I need to approach this differently if I don't want to install office on the server this will be automated on?

Comment: If a certain software uses Access as database, the software can still manipulate the database even without Microsoft Office, I'm not entirely sure if you can find the Excel Object Library without Office, if you can then you don't need Office installed, but you'll this DLL to perform Excel functions :)

Comment: I just thought of this, you can probably grab the Excel DLL from another computer with office installed. This should most likely work.

Answer (score 0):

Writing data to existing Excel files is the simplest task. You need to use `microsoft.ace.oledb.<version>` to connect to Excel file like it is a database

This is connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

You will be writing to sheet like to table, no different.

Here you will find all necessary code examples

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Excel-Sheet-Helper-helper-4f433579